# Problems with installation of Zend-framework

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, ubuntu

When I type this command:

```
apt-get install zend-framework
```

I am getting this error:

```
dpkg: error processing zend-framework (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-common
 php5-cli
 libapache2-mod-php5
 php5-curl
 php5-gd
 php5-intl
 php5-mysql
 php5-pspell
 php5-recode
 php5-snmp
 php5-sqlite
 php5-tidy
 php5-xmlrpc
 php5-xsl
 php-pear
 php5
 libzend-framework-php
 zend-framework-bin
 zend-framework
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have already install apache2, php5 and mysql on my Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing dependencies

I would suggest using composer.

1) install composer as shown here https://getcomposer.org/download/

2) create the composer.json file http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer

3) install zend using composer from the instructions given above